# problema al realizar calculo

Tags: python, tkinter

Hola gente buenas noches, les comento mi pequeño problema.

estoy haciendo una pequeña prueba con python y Tkinter , esta consiste en 2 clases una llamada Condiciones
y otra llamada divisas.

la primera al aceptar los términos me llama a la clase divisas, llevandome a sus funciones.
debo  ingresar un numero en la entrada uno y en la entrada dos, esta al presionar el botón
debe devolverme un resultado en la label ubicada abajo.
el tema es que al realizar el calculo , esta me tira error en base 10, me fije y refije y nada, probé viendo otros ejercicios míos similares y salen bien. Ahora lo que hice fue agarrar esa clase divisas y ejecutarla solo a ella, y me dan los resultados.  agrego que soy nuevo en esto.
muchas gracias de antemano.

import Tkinter as t
import ttk

class condiciones:
def **init**(self):
self.ventana_condiciones=t.Tk()
self.dato_condicion=t.IntVar()
self.check_condicion=ttk.Checkbutton(self.ventana_condiciones, text="al aceptar usted es responsabl", variable=self.dato_condicion ,command=self.confirma)
self.check_condicion.grid(column=1,row=5 )

```
    self.boton_confirma=ttk.Button(self.ventana_condiciones, text="confirmar",state="disabled" ,command=self.ingreso)
    self.boton_confirma.grid(column=3, row=5)


    self.ventana_condiciones.mainloop()

def confirma(self):
    if self.dato_condicion.get()==0:
        self.boton_confirma.configure(state="disabled")
    if self.dato_condicion.get()==1:
        self.boton_confirma.configure(state="normal")

def ingreso(self):
    divisas()
```

class divisas:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.ventana_divisas=t.Tk()
    self.ventana_divisas.title("BIENVENIDOS")
    self.la_comunicado=ttk.Label(self.ventana_divisas, text="en la primera casilla aplique el precio de compra")
    self.la_comunicado.grid(column=3, row=2)
    
    self.entrada1=t.StringVar()
    self.moneda_uno=ttk.Entry(self.ventana_divisas, width=10, textvariable=self.entrada1)
    self.moneda_uno.grid(column=3, row=3)

    self.entrada2=t.StringVar()
    self.moneda_dos=ttk.Entry(self.ventana_divisas, width=10, textvariable=self.entrada2)
    self.moneda_dos.grid(column=3, row=6)


    self.boton_calculo=ttk.Button(self.ventana_divisas, text="convertir", command=self.convertir)
    self.boton_calculo.grid(column=3, row=7)

    
    self.labell=ttk.Label(self.ventana_divisas, text="")
    self.labell.grid(column=3, row=8)

    self.ventana_divisas.mainloop()


def convertir(self):
    v1=int(self.entrada1.get())
    v2=int(self.entrada2.get())
    calculo=v1*v2
    self.labell.configure(text=calculo)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenido Yali Huespe! c:

Curioso y extraño error con el que te topaste!

## Motivo

Probando distintos escenarios, vi que el error ocurre siempre que tengas 2 o más ventanas principales (las creadas con `t.Tk()`) abiertas.
Mis conclusiones las obtuve con prueba y error, por lo que no se más sobre que hace que ocurra esto. Si alguien tiene más información, por favor agregue un comentario con la explicación.

## Que es lo que sucede?

Los StringVars adquieren un valor inicial (por default inician con una cadena vacía) pero no se actualizan. Es decir, sin importar lo que escriba el usuario en los Entrys, el valor del StringVar no cambia.

Una vez apretas el botón convertir, tu función intenta transformar el contenido de los StringVars, pero int no puede convertir cadenas vacias en numeros, por lo que se produce un error.

## Solución 1: Toplevel

En lugar de crear dos ventanas principales, haz que la ventana de la clase divisas sea un [Toplevel](https://riptutorial.com/tkinter/example/22130/difference-between-tk-and-toplevel). Puedes hacer que la ventana de la clase divisas sea un Toplevel cambiando esta linea de la clase divisas `self.ventana_divisas=t.Tk()` por `self.ventana_divisas=t.Toplevel()`.

Un Toplevel es una ventana hija de otra ventana. Es igual a la ventana principal.
La desventaja de un Toplevel es que si cerrás su ventana padre, el Toplevel mismo se cerrará.

## Solución 2: Cierra la ventana de la clase condiciones

Para no tener las dos ventanas abiertas a la vez, puedes cerrar la primera. Para lograrlo, cambia la función ingreso dentro de condiciones por:

```
def ingreso(self):
    # Cierra la ventana de la clase condiciones
    self.ventana_condiciones.destroy()
    divisas()
```

## Solucion 3: Crea los StringVars en la segunda ventana.

Si insistes en mantener abiertas las dos ventanas sin tener que crear un Toplevel, esta es la solución más adecuada.

Las variables de control (StringVar, Intvar, etc), al igual que los widgets, pueden ser creadas en una ventana especifica. Si no le pasas de primer argumento a una variable de control, dicha se creará en la ventana principal.

Esta solución consiste en que los StringVars se creen en la ventana de la clase divisas. Entonces el código de la funcion `__init__` de la clase divisas quedaría así:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.ventana_divisas=t.Tk()
    self.ventana_divisas.title("BIENVENIDOS")
    self.la_comunicado=ttk.Label(self.ventana_divisas, text="en la primera casilla aplique el precio de compra")
    self.la_comunicado.grid(column=3, row=2)

    # Creo el StringVar y le indico que lo cree en la ventana "ventana_divisas"
    self.entrada1=t.StringVar(self.ventana_divisas)
    self.moneda_uno=ttk.Entry(self.ventana_divisas, width=10, textvariable=self.entrada1)
    self.moneda_uno.grid(column=3, row=3)

    # Aqui hago lo mismo
    self.entrada2=t.StringVar(self.ventana_divisas)
    self.moneda_dos=ttk.Entry(self.ventana_divisas, width=10, textvariable=self.entrada2)
    self.moneda_dos.grid(column=3, row=6)


    self.boton_calculo=ttk.Button(self.ventana_divisas, text="convertir", command=self.convertir)
    self.boton_calculo.grid(column=3, row=7)


    self.labell=ttk.Label(self.ventana_divisas, text="")
    self.labell.grid(column=3, row=8)

    self.ventana_divisas.mainloop()
```

Lo malo de esta solución es que tendrás que aplicarla cada vez que crees un nuevo StringVar.

Espero que mi respuesta te sirva, si no entendés algo, dime c:

Comment: MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS,
tome la solucion 2, destroy(), con eso el calculo se realiza tranquilamente..

ahora voy a ponerme a indagar el porque de ese conflicto.